# Regex JSon Quote Cleaner

Tags: json, regex

I've got some JSON coming in that is occasionally dirty with random quotes inserted. As an example :

"contact_interests": "Interests:|Poet - Several poems have been published.  One poem was set to music, recorded and released in 1972.  A recent poem |"Little Brother|" has been set to music and will be recorded and released by 2014.Read |"mystery books, love long walks/hikes, prayer, family.|",

We need to find and replace all occurrences of |" except for the case where it's those characters terminate a line (|",)

What would be the Regex to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Does that mean all instances not followed by a comma? `(?!\|",)\|"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
\|"(?=[^,])
```

It will match |" that isn't followed by a comma